# Change root path from .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to change "/" to "/folder".

So when user clicks link with this url "/page.php" I want it to be automatically translated by .htaccess to "/folder/page.php".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This simple rule should work for you in site root .htaccess (parent directory of `folder`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* folder/$0 [L]
```

Comment: This works, but only in case you put path in Url, in code I have this <a href="/login">click</a> 

I want that .htaccess changed this url dynamically with "/folder/login" when user clicks this a attribute.

Comment: Didn't understand your comment. If HTML link is `<a href="/login">click</a>` the this rule will internally load `/folder/login` but browser address will still show `/login`. Do you want browser address to change to `/folder/login` as well?

Answer (score 1):

**Please use .htaccess file. i think its better for you.**

Your Need is:

```
HTTP://YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/page.php

TO 

HTTP://YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/FOLDER/page.php
```

Step1:

```
create an .htaccess file on your Server

Filename: .htaccess
```

just Copy this part and Change the Values.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} YOUR_DOMAIN.COM$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !FOLDER
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/FOLDER/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**[Reference-1](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)** | 
**[Reference-2](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)**